# ¿Es posible que $_POST solo seleccione textarea que posean un value?

Tags: javascript, php, formularios

Poseo 2 páginas web, una que es la principal (un formulario), el cual estoy pidiendo unos datos mediante textarea y con un botón les doy la opción de poder generar más textarea para poder continuar escribiendo.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
        function confirmExit(){
            return "Ha intentado salir de esta pagina. Si ha realizado algun cambio en los campos sin hacer clic en el boton Guardar, los cambios se perderan. Seguro que desea salir de esta pagina? ";
        }

        var table_inputs = 0;
        function addTextarea(id, name) {
            var table     = document.getElementById(id);
            var row       = table.insertRow(2);
            var cell      = row.insertCell(0);
            var input     = document.createElement("textarea");
            table_inputs++;
            input.rows    = "4";
            input.cols    = "170";
            input.name    = name + table_inputs;
            input.id      = id + table_inputs;
            var campo     = document.createElement("input");
            campo.type    = "button";
            campo.value   = "Borrar";
            campo.onclick = function () {
                var fila  = this.parentNode.parentNode;
                var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
                tbody.removeChild(fila);
            }
            cell.appendChild(input);
            cell.appendChild(campo);
        }

        function vaciar_campo(input1) {
            input1.value = "";
        }
    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <form name="formulario" id="formulario" action="creador.php" method="post" width="30%">
        <table id="tablafecha" border="3" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td><h1>Fecha y número</h1>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fecha: <input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha"><br>
                    Número: <input type="number" name="numero" id="numero">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table id="tesisTable" border="3" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td><h1>TESIS DOCTORAL</h1>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <textarea name="tesis" id="tesis" rows="4" cols="170"></textarea>
                    <button onclick="addTextarea('tesisTable', 'tesis')" type="button" name="tesis2" id="tesis2">Añadir</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

En esta otra página, lo que hago es recuperar el contenido de todos los textarea e implementarlos en una página con unos estilos que le asigno.

```
  <?php
     $post = [];

  if( !empty( $_POST ) )
  {
    $post = $_POST;
  }

  $tesis        = array_intersect_key( $post, array_flip( preg_grep( '/^tesis[0-9]*/i', array_keys( $post ) ) ) );
  $subvenciones = array_intersect_key( $post, array_flip( preg_grep( '/^subvenciones[0-9]*/i', array_keys( $post ) ) ) );
  $otrainfo     = array_intersect_key( $post, array_flip( preg_grep( '/^otrainfo[0-9]*/i', array_keys( $post ) ) ) );
  $actualidad   = array_intersect_key( $post, array_flip( preg_grep( '/^actualidad[0-9]*/i', array_keys( $post ) ) ) );
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var fecha ="<?php echo $_POST['fecha']; ?>";
  var numero ="<?php echo $_POST['numero']; ?>";
  var datos ="<?php foreach( $tesis as $key => $value ): ?><ul style='margin-top:0cm' type=disc><li class=MsoNormal style='margin-right:11.35pt;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1;tab-stops:list 36.0pt'><span style='font-family:'Arial','sans-serif';mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman''><?php echo $value; ?></span></li></ul><?php endforeach; ?>";
```

Mi duda es, ¿existe alguna manera de modificar o decirle a $_POST que no me coja los textarea que no han sido rellenados en el formulario? ¿O existe alguna otra manera de realizar esta operación de manera más fácil? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma rápida y directa es [array_filter](http://es.php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php).

```
if( !empty( $_POST ) )
{
    $filter = array_filter($_POST); # <-- me falto cerrar
    $post   = $filter;
}
```

No lo he probado, pero creo que debería cumplir con lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y me ha dado el siguiente error: syntax error, unexpected '$post' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Es porque faltaba un punto y coma

Comment: @OscarSanclemente Perdón, ya lo he corregido. Me faltó cerrar la línea.

Comment: Gracias @amenadiel justo estaba editándolo.

Comment: Gracias a los dos por la ayuda prestada. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de @OscarR. soluciona tu problema muy bien. Sin embargo, siempre es importante conocer distintas formas. Aquí te muestro una forma de hacerlo desde el cliente:

```
function sendTexts (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = e.target;

  let textareas = form.querySelectorAll('textarea');
  let empty = [].filter.call(textareas, function (textarea) {
    if (textarea.value === '') { return textarea; }
  });

  empty.forEach(function (textarea) {
    form.removeChild(textarea);
  });

  form.submit();
}
```

Simplemente se captura el evento `submit` del formulario y se hace obtienen los textareas que estén vacíos; estos elementos son borrados del formulario y es enviado. Esto pasará muy rápido que no se notará, así que será transparente para el usuario final.